# Shielding a visa paywave card

Tags: smart-card

I live in Melbourne Australia, and I know that if you had two myki's close together they prevent each other from working causing a "multiple cards detected" message to appear. I was wondering if this would work similarly for a debit card, as the bank f'd up and sent me a card with the first and last name mixed up, so I got a replacement with the right name, would the two cards prevent each other from working?

This could be tested with a new card and an expired one as they both still have the technology to communicate, simplified, i'm asking if it works like a simplex radio or a duplex radio (this is an analogy, I dont want to know about radio's right now).

I welcome all input relating to the question at hand and all attempts at making it easier to understand, i am not too good at explaining idea's and wording things on paper/keyboard whilst i have better luck with typing it than writing it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HF RFID tags typically support anti-collision so the reader may be able to identify both cards. It would then have to decide which card to charge.  so using a second card to mask the other card may not work. If the second card does not get enough RF to operate, the reader has no conundrum, or the reader may just charge the first card it sees.

For blocking reads you'll probably get better results with card-sized metal rectangle this will significantly reduce the signal available to any card it is beside. thin aluminium sheet from a soft-drink (or beer) can or an oven tray should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the frequency of the chip, I wouldn't rely on that to have my cards safe.

If you want to be safe, just put a sheet of aluminium on your wallet that is somewhere in parallel to the cards.

Otherwise there are some RFID-safe wallets that are in metal that will protect the cards.

Comment: Chewing gum wrappers should work just as well. The thin foils, copper or aluminum, begin to shield about 4MHz. At 400MHz, the shielding is nearly 100dB. At 2,000MHz, the shielding is near 200db. Chew gum.

Comment: Paywave is 13.56 MHz